# 値を取得するコードを追加したい

Tags: vba

`wItem(i) = FoundCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value`の部分で機能プログラム名の値は、取得されて表示されたのですが、この、値を取得する処理をもう3件追加したいです。参照するエクセルは同じなのですが、取得したいセルの位置はそれぞれ異なります。どのようにしたらうまくいくでしょうか。

```
    Sub 単体テスト仕様書マクロ()
Dim wFile       As String
Dim wFilePath   As String
Dim i           As Long
 
'Excelファイルが存在していたらファイル名を返す
wFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")
 
'先頭行を指定
i = 2
 
'カレントディレクトリに存在するExcelファイルを全て読み込む
Do While wFile <> ""
     
    '開くExcelファイルのフルパスを取得
    wFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & wFile
     
    '機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名・テスト件数・完了数・不具合件数を取得し配列に格納する（区切り文字：|）
    strData = Split(File_Load(wFilePath), "|")
     
    '機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名
    Cells(i, 1) = strData(0)
     
    'テスト件数
    Cells(i, 3) = strData(1)
     
    '完了数
    Cells(i, 5) = strData(2)
    
    '不具合件数
    
    Cells(i, 7) = strData(3)
      
     
    '次のExcelファイルを取得
    wFile = Dir()
     
    '行数をカウント
    i = i + 1
 
Loop
 
    MsgBox "完了"
End Sub

Function File_Load(ByVal wFilePath As String) As String

    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wItem       As Variant
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim FoundCell   As Object

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFilePath)

    wItem = Array("機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名", "テスト件数", "完了数", "不具合件数")

    For i = LBound(wItem) To UBound(wItem)

        Set FoundCell = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=wItem(i))

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            wItem(i) = ""
        Else
            wItem(i) = FoundCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value
        End If

    Next i

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    File_Load = Join(wItem, "|")


End Function
```

[image: 機能プログラム名だけは取得できたのですが、ほかの３つも同様の処理で取得したいです。]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File_Load`ファンクションの下記を直してみてください。

```
Else
    ' wItem(i) = FoundCell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value '修正前
    wItem(i) = FoundCell.Offset(1, 0).Value       '修正後
End If
```

[Findメソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)は値の見つかった範囲(`Range`)を返しますので、そこからの相対位置を取得しなければいけません。
つまり`wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="テスト件数")`とした場合は、"テスト件数"が見つかった`B1`などがFoundCellに入ります。
なので`B1`に対して`Offset(1, 0)`を指定することで`B2`の値を読み取ることができます。

Comment: うまくできました。本当にありがとうございました。すごく助かりました。また、機会がありましたら、よろしくお願いします。